# attached to a method? code understanding

Tags: angularjs, javascript

In the codebase that I am trying to figure out, I see that a js file (myloopfile.js) being imported into another js file. I am trying to make sense of some of the code used there

this is myloopfile.js

```
function method1(value) {
    // return something 
}

var myLooper = function (obj, iterator, context) {
    var key;
    if (obj) {
        if (typeof obj === 'function') {
            for (key in obj) {
                if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && (!obj.hasOwnProperty || obj.hasOwnProperty(key))) {
                    iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
                }
            }
        } else if (obj.forEach && obj.forEach !== forEach) {
            obj.forEach(iterator, context);
        } else if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
            for (key = 0; key < obj.length; key++)
                iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
        } else {
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
};
```

……………………………………………………………………………….

the myLoop in myloopfile.js is called like this

```
var looper = require(‘../myloopfile.js);

looper({
        loop1: function(Home) { //do something },
        loop2: function(Home) { //dosomething }
    }, function(return1, return2) {
        //do something else
    });
```

I am trying to find out where this

```
function(return1, return2) {
        //do something else
});
```

coming from ? I don’t see anything in that file that suggests that there is a method attached to it. Also where are the parameters return1 and return2 coming from? is this some javascript way to attach things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myLooper = function (obj, iterator, context) {
    /* .... */
    iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
    /* .... */
};
```

You pass:

```
looper({
    loop1: function(Home) { //do something },
    loop2: function(Home) { //dosomething }
}, function(return1, return2) {
    //do something else
});
```

So

```
obj = {
    loop1: function(Home) { //do something },
    loop2: function(Home) { //dosomething }
}
```

and

```
iterator = function(return1, return2) {
    //do something else
}
```

The `Function.prototype.call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually. Therefore, inside you iterator function:

```
this = context;
return1 = obj[key];
return2 = key;
```

Comment: if thats the case when I do looper({
    loop1: function(Home) { //do something },
    loop2: function(Home) { //dosomething }
}, function(return1, return2, return3) {
    //do something else
});  I get return3 in undefined....where as with your explaination it seems like I should have had three available, context, obj[key] and key

Comment: No, because `.call` sets the first parameter as `this`

Comment: ahh...ok... and then the file myloopfile.js looks like that its just bunch of methods... so how does this syntax looper({
    loop1: function(Home) { //do something },
    loop2: function(Home) { //dosomething }
}, gets executed...I mean I see it takes 3 parameters but thats about it

Comment: It gets executed when you create the looper "object"

Comment: `looper` is a function, so you just simply call it. You don't specifiy the third argument, so `context` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

So javascript has function that are called `anonymous function` that don't need a function name.

Basically it is used (in this instance) as a way to be an expantion of a parameter.

Take for example the javascript function `setTimeout`

Well `setTimeout` can take an anonymous function as one of its parameters i.e

```
var timer = setTimeout(function{
                          //do something
                         },
                       2000); 

 // setTimeout(function, time, paramters)
```

So you don't have to declare a function and pass it in as a parameter

Back to your case, you have this anonymous function that takes return1 and return2

So in the end:

```
  return1 = obj[key];
  return2 = key;
```

Comment: and thats where I am confused. Where is it defined that take return1 and return2...why can I not do return1, return2, return3...?

Comment: In `var myLooper = function (obj, iterator, context)` The obj is the functions `loop1, loop2` , the iterator is the function `function(return1, return2,)` and the context is `return1, return2` it is all just a syntax thing